# Python: does Gevent 1.0 support Python 3.3?

Tags: python-3.x, gevent

I'm currently using it with 2.7, but thinking of moving to 3.3. The documentation didn't specify if it was compatible with 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [pypi gevent package page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gevent/1.0), it does not support Python 3.x.

```
...
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.5
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6
Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7
...
```